# notifyDataSetChanged not working after data fetch, the second time - ListView won't refresh

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-volley

I have a fragment containing a listview which fetches data from the network using Volley and on response, the list retrieved is displayed in the listview using a custom arrayadapter.

The issue is that the first time this is loaded, all works good; but when closing the activity and going back in, the listview is never refreshed on response. I'd need to force close the app for it to work once more. One thing I noticed is that getActivity() is null at this stage. this.activity is not.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_interests, container, false);

    // Set the adapter
    mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) mListView).setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Set OnItemClickListener so we can be notified on item clicks
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SelectionListContent.getItems().clear();
    SelectionListContent.ITEMS.add(new SelectionListContent.Item("0", "Loading...", false));
    mAdapter = new SelectionListViewAdapter(this.activity,
            R.layout.listviewcheckbox, SelectionListContent.ITEMS);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    CategoriesData.getInstance(this.activity, new CategoriesData.CategoriesDataListener() {
        @Override
        public void gotCategories(List<HashMap<String, Object>> categories) {
            InterestsFragment.this.categories = categories;
            reloadtable();
        }
    }).getCategories();
}

public void reloadtable() {
    SelectionListContent.ITEMS.clear();
    Object interests = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().get("interests");
    List<HashMap<String, String>> selected = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    if (interests != null) {
        selected = (List<HashMap<String, String>>) interests;
    }
    for (HashMap<String, Object> obj : categories) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (HashMap<String, String> o : selected) {
            if (o.containsKey(obj.get("id").toString())) {
                found = true;
            }
        }
        SelectionListContent.Item i = new SelectionListContent.Item((String) obj.get("id"), (String) obj.get("name"), found);
        SelectionListContent.ITEMS.add(i);
    }

    mListView.destroyDrawingCache();
    mListView.setVisibility(ListView.INVISIBLE);
    mListView.setVisibility(ListView.VISIBLE);
    ((ArrayAdapter)mAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Update 1:** It seems that which the notifyDataSetChanged() is being called, the getView() inside the adapter stops being called after fetching the data for the second time.

**Update 2:** Tried changing notifyDataSetChanged() to

```
    mAdapter = new SelectionListViewAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.listviewcheckbox, SelectionListContent.ITEMS);
    mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) mListView).setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

and it crashes on the first line. getActivity() is null at this stage. This doesn't happen if I use the pointer reference I kept as a property in the fragment. Not sure if this can be causing the original issue

Comment: It may be due to when you come back to activity it will run OnResume method. try to reload data in onResume method too.

Comment: No it won't budget... the loading item appears but the data isn't displayed. activity, listview and adapter are not null and the data is present. It just mysteriously never shows up on display. Please note that I am refetching data from the network every time as well.

Comment: Use the Onreusme to call yours network data..

Comment: Thanks good to know! The problem still persists though unfortunately...

Comment: put some log and check whether the reload data function get called, and also put some log in the getView function in the adapter to see how is the data array looks like after the notifyDataSetChanged() function

Comment: from the logs it shows that the notiftyDataSetChanged() is being called and there are items in the data array but the getView() is not being called.

Comment: you should set adapter in reloadtable() function once new data is fetched.

Comment: tried setting the adapter from scratch using: mAdapter = new SelectionListViewAdapter(this.activity, R.layout.listviewcheckbox, SelectionListContent.ITEMS);
mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) mListView).setAdapter(mAdapter); but still no luck. One thing I noticed is that if I use getActivity() instead of this.activity at that point, getActivity() is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
((ArrayAdapter)mAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

before this use this

```
mAdapter.clear();
mAdapter.addAll(newlist);
((ArrayAdapter)mAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: This didn't make it work. The SelectionListContent.ITEMS counts as the data for the adapter directly and I'm already clearing and adding new data in the reloadtable() function.